# Use a column both as source and target of a single update query

Tags: sql-server-2008, transactions

I'm trying to perform an update over a couple of fields in my table, in order to switch their values (thanks to some faulty logic in the piece of software generating the data, which is out of my contorol).

The query I'd use would look like this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SET @MyQuery = 'UPDATE myTable SET ColumnA = ColumnB, ColumnB = ColumnC WHERE myConditions'
EXEC @MyQuery
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Or, it would look like this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SET @MyQuery = 'UPDATE myTable SET ColumnA = ColumnB WHERE myConditions'
SET @MyQuery2 = 'UPDATE myTable SET ColumnB = ColumnC WHERE myConditions'
EXEC @MyQuery
EXEC @MyQuery2
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

I'm pretty sure splitting up the queries guarantees the result I want, but it would be much easier (less all-around editing) if I could safely assume a single query would be solid.

Would the former query achieve the same result as the latter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

```
UPDATE myTable
SET    ColumnA = ColumnB,
       ColumnB = ColumnC
WHERE  myConditions
```

will work fine. Conceptually the assignments happen ["all at once"](http://www.ndc2010.no/index.aspx?id=268800) in SQL so the following would work too to swap two column values directly.

```
UPDATE myTable
SET    ColumnA = ColumnB,
       ColumnB = ColumnA 
WHERE  myConditions
```